# The field, constructor or member 'MapRoute' is not defined in F# Web API Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#, c#-to-f#

I'm taking my first steps in F# development and I've ran in the following issue; I'm trying to setup the routing of an web api and when I try using the MapRoute method of a RouteCollection I get the following error:

> The field, constructor or member 'MapRoute' is not defined

For the project I used the F# MVC 5 templates from Daniel Mohl, I've tried using Web API nuget packages and referencing System.Web.Mvc where the RouteMap extensions seems to reside. I've read that extensions methods (which MapRoute seems to be) can cause problems, but I've no clue how to fix it. Also I saw suggestions loading references in the Interactive window, but that didn't work either (seems not surprisingly). My questions is now what is the best approach here in creating a pure F# Web API project? (I've also read this http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/08/23/how-to-create-a-pure-f-aspnet-web-api-project/, but it seems a bit outdated) Sub questions how do I solve errors like this in the future?

Comment: MVC uses `MapRoute`, WebAPI uses `MapHttpRoute` - which are you using MVC or WebAPI?

Comment: What's outdated about my blog post? I used it as recently as last month as a recipe for a new API I'm developing for a client.

Comment: @Mark, the approach seems a bit outdated ;) I was hoping to use the templates instead of 'hacking' it together.

@ James, I'm using Web API and I got probaly need MapHttpRoute then. I'm guess I got a little bit tunnelvision getting stuff to work :)

Comment: Tunnelvision confirmed and I might then use your approach in the future Mark

Comment: Do you consider your question resolved then, or is there still something we can help you with?

Comment: Resolved yes, I've run into new different problems I'll try to resolve myself.